# Difference between polynomial regression and polynomial kernel

Tags: regression, kernel-trick, feature-engineering

A [few answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463226/how-to-do-gaussian-polynomial-regression-with-scikit-learn) on SO suggested that a polynomial transformation and a regularized regression can be used instead of a polynomial kernel regression. What's the difference between them?

I thought polynomial feature transformation of degree `d` has combinatorially many parameters, while polynomial kernel has no parameters at all once `d` is fixed. So without regularization, polynomial feature transformation should result in a much higher complexity / flexibility of the model. Does L1 or L2 regularization after adding polynomial features make two approaches somewhat similar?